# In SVN, what's the different between "merge from a to b" an "merge from b to a"?

Tags: svn, merge

I'm confused about SVN merge.

What's the difference between "merge from a to b" and "merge from b to a"?

Answer (score 0):

"Merge from b to a" changes "a".  "Merge from a to b" changes "b".

Answer (score 0):

Merge from A to B means take a series of changes applied to A, a repository URL, and apply them to B, which is a Working Copy, which you almost always ought to build and test before committing. ‘A’ could be a maintenance branch (`branches/1.0`) in which you have fixed a problem in your released version 1.0, and of course committed the solution to your repository; now you want to make sure the same problem is fixed in the `trunk` (which is thus ‘B’), where you are developing the next version. The other way round would mean that you had fixed the problem in your new version and realised you needed to release a patch, such as 1.0.01.